# Mongodb query on triple nested array of object

Tags: json, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having some problem to write a query to return a triple nested value from a document. The documents I'm using are structured like this

```
{
  "areaname": "name1",
  "places": [
    {
      "placename": "place1",
      "objects": [
        {
          "objname": "obj1",
          "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "objname": "obj2",
          "tags": [
            "tag6",
            "tag7"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "placename": "place2",
      "objects": [
        {
          "objname": "obj45",
          "tags": [
            "tag46",
            "tag34"
          ]
        },
        {
          "objname": "obj77",
          "tags": [
            "tag56",
            "tag11"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It is quite simple actually but I can't find a solution to a simple query like:
"return the objname of the object that contains tag1 inside their tag"

So for the give document if I use "tag1" as a parameter it is expected for the query to return "obj1"
It should give me the same result if I use "tag2" as a parameter
Other example: using "tag56" it should return only "obj77"

Right now i have no problem returning the whole document using the dot-notation or top level field such as areaname or others

```
db.users.find( {"places.objects.tags":"tag1"}, { areaname: 1, _id:0 } )
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: you mind using an aggregation pipeline or it has to be a query? you cant really do it using just a simple find as its structure manipulation powers are limited.

Comment: yeah it can be an aggregation pipeline too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it simple:

```
[
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "places.objects.tags" : "tag1"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$places"
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$places.objects"
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "places.objects.tags" : "tag1"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$_id", 
                "obj_names" : {
                    "$push" : "$places.objects.objname"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
```

You should add any other fields you want to keep to the group stage,
this can also be done without the double $unwind stage but i choose this for read-ability.

Comment: what do you think about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587116/upsert-mongo-array-of-object-with-condition