# Upsert mongo array of object with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, apache-nifi

I have a collection with some documents and each document has ha list of objects representing a temporal interval in epoch with a keyword. I want to update the final value of the interval of each object in the right document where the ending value is greater than a value. If nothing can be updated I want to insert a new interval with both start and end as the new value and with the keyword used in the query.

I'm using nifi to perform this task and the update block, with upsert enabled. I can use aggregation too but it should be possible to just do it with an upsert.

This is what I have in place right now

```
QUERY
{
    "_id":"docid",
    "thearray.keyword": "red",
    "thearray.end": {$gte :minUpdatable}
}
```

and this as the update body:

```
UPDATE BODY
{
      "thearray.$[].end": valueToUpdate,
      "$setOnInsert":{"$push": {"thearray":{"keyword":"red","start":valueToUpdate,"end":valueToUpdate}}}
    }
}
```

This is the document data structure:
INITITAL STATUS

```
{
  _id:"docid",
  otherInfo:"",
  thearray:[
    {keyword:"red",start:8,end:15},
    {keyword:"blue",start:8,end:15},
    {keyword:"red",start:8,end:9},
    {keyword:"red",start:9,end:16},
    ...
  ]
}
```

EXAMPLE 1: In this situation, from initial status, updating with "docid" as the document, "red" as keyword, 12 as lower possible end value to update (minUpdatable) and 22 as the value to set the document should become something like:

```
{
  _id:"docid",
  otherInfo:"",
  thearray:[
    {keyword:"red",start:8,end:22},
    {keyword:"blue",start:8,end:15},
    {keyword:"red",start:8,end:9},
    {keyword:"red",start:9,end:22},
    ...
  ]
}
```

EXAMPLE 2: In the same situation, from initial status, updating with with "docid" as the document, "red" as keyword, 33 as lower possible end value to update and 39 as the value to set the document should result in something like (or any query that result in the impossibility to update) :

```
{
  _id:"docid",
  otherInfo:"",
  thearray:[
    {keyword:"red",start:8,end:15},
    {keyword:"blue",start:8,end:15},
    {keyword:"red",start:8,end:9},
    {keyword:"red",start:9,end:16},
    ...,
    {keyword:"red",start:33,end:33}
  ]
}
```